# Which GUI library does Google Chrome use?

Tags: user-interface, google-chrome

What GUI library does Google Chrome use?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of May 2014 Google Chrome uses it's own custom UI stack called [Aura](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura). This is currently the case for all platforms except OSX.

References:

- [PSA: Aura Plans](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/UMwGGgP0P9c)
- [Google Replacing GTK2 With Aura in Chrome 35](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTYyNzQ)

Answer (score 32):

On Linux it uses GTK+, on Mac OS X Cocoa, and on Windows a custom views library, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsvNebq1dRg and also documents from http://dev.chromium.org:

- http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromeviews
- http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/views-windowing

Answer (score 11):

You probably want their document entitled "[Conventions and patterns for multi-platform development](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/conventions-and-patterns-for-multi-platform-development)." Your answer is

```
Mac -> Cocoa,
Linux -> GTK,
Windows -> Their own custom "Windows Views"
```

You'll also see have an experimental "GTK Views", so it sounds like they're aiming for their own abstraction?

Answer (score 8):

On Windows [WTL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode33MicrosoftOpenSourceInsideGoogleChrome.aspx) for the (well...) chrome, and WebKit for the HTML rendering.

Answer (score 5):

WTL on Windows, as Shay said. All UI in the Mac and Linux versions is being written from scratch in Cocoa and GTK+ respectively. Only the logic (and WebKit, which renders the web pages) is fully cross-platform.