# How does the Google Chrome GUI Compile Cross Platform? 

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, google-chrome

What GUI framework is the Google Chrome browser using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which GUI library does Google Chrome use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874609/which-gui-library-does-google-chrome-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874609/what-gui-library-does-google-chrome-use)