# Can i use the google chrome gui library code for own desktop applications?:

Tags: user-interface, google-chrome, wxwidgets

I mean is it useable like WxWidgets to develop total non web releated client apps. A HTML widget is always nice but does it provide all the other common widgets a typical appication needs?

Is it hard to generate a build script for an chrome based application or are the make files full of chrome specific paths and targets.

EDIT: I know that it is based on Webkit which is in QT. But for a webbrowser you need much mnore then the WebKit Widget. So it contains a complete GUI Toolkit which is native. It means it uses Cocoa on MacOSX and GTK on Unix/Linux and Win32/WTL on Windows. But at some level they have to create a common API again. So it has to be like WxWidgets a crossplatform toolkit. The question is if this is useable for development of a different API.

Please answer only if you understand how Chrome is designed.

And no i don't want to look at QT as it is not pure Cocoa (it's only using NSView and Appearance Manager) and i don't want WxWidgets as this is bloated and you see the design of 1992 together with very late Cocoa patches.

Comment: What is it that you want from Chrome? the UI? the HTML rederer? What?

Comment: Your question is substantially answered by the question "[Which GUI library does Google Chrome use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874609/which-gui-library-does-google-chrome-use)".

Comment: @Lothar, why exactly do you want to use web engine to develop desktop application?

Comment: 14 years ago when i asked this question there was no way that everything could be done in HTML and XULRunner from Mozilla was a GUI library abstraction using Cocoa Widgets on MacOS and Gtk on Linux. It was at the time when Firefox aborted this project and i had hope that Chrome would offer somthing under the hood like that to make the interface look native (was a big thing back then).

Answer (score 3):

I think the original question was more along the lines of "Does Chrome have something like XULRunner?" to code off of as a platform.

The Chromium team is working on something called app_shell which should allow Chrome Packaged Apps to be compiled to run separately from the browser. In effect you will be able to write an HTML5/CSS/JS Chrome app that runs similar to a native applications completely independently of chrome.

More info:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=288226

Comment: Upvoted because at least somebody seems to understand my question - even if he don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is [heavily based](http://arstechnica.com/security/news/2008/09/chrome-antics-did-google-reverse-engineer.ars) upon the Win32 API. That's why porting it is a tough job.

If you want only the HTML renderer, you would want [webkit](http://webkit.org/) and [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).

**EDIT:**

> It means it uses Cocoa on MacOSX and
>   GTK on Unix/Linux and Win32/WTL on
>   Windows

Well, what do you expect? each of those have it's own native implementation and a set of patches. [GTK's](http://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk) being the latest one, Windows and Mac OSX are rather obvious since Webkit is Apple's so they had to make it work with OSX, and Windows port of Safari.

Each of those is *native* port coded specifically for the targeted platform, it is *not* a wrapper/library like Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: This was only true for the first initial release, they now have a GTK and a Cocoa version.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to try [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) instead. It contains a browser widget based on WebKit (which is what Chrome uses as well) and it's nicely integrated with the rest of the library. Since it's primarily a GUI library, not a browser, it's easy to build applications based on it. I'm not sure if you can easily take out the Chrome GUI library.