# How does Google Chrome UI work under the hood?

Tags: google-chrome

Custom user interfaces such as tabs, buttons, and Omnibox look the same across all platforms.  How is this achieved?  It doesn't seem like platform-dependent UI is used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which GUI library does Google Chrome use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874609/which-gui-library-does-google-chrome-use)

Comment: I think this question was geared towards cross-platform drawing libraries rather than GUI/WM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome uses Skia.  Here is an example (Gtk+ 3, cairo, skia):

```
  g_signal_connect(window_container_, "draw",
                   G_CALLBACK(OnWindowContainerDraw), NULL);

gboolean OnWindowContainerDraw(GtkWidget* widget,
                               cairo_t *cr) {                  
  SkBitmap bitmap;
  bitmap.setConfig(SkBitmap::kARGB_8888_Config, 100, 100);
  bitmap.allocPixels();

  SkDevice device(bitmap);
  SkCanvas canvas(&device);
  SkPaint paint;
  SkRect r;

  paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
  r.set(10, 10, 20, 20);
  canvas.drawRect(r, paint);

  cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(
      (unsigned char*)bitmap.getPixels(), CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
      bitmap.width(), bitmap.height(), bitmap.rowBytes());
  cairo_surface_mark_dirty(surface);
  cairo_set_source_surface(cr, surface, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint(cr);

  return FALSE;
}
```